# Developing android apps

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app which will be help a shop owner can input his daily sales expense, employee history, product setting and it show day to day or monthly profit. when he use this app no need to connect internet connectivity. data all are store in sd card but if he want in internet connectivity state he can save data in dropbox. So as like a financial app when I build this which program I need to know like java, xml ?? there are need any database program ??? I am a new Apps Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a good understanding of Android fundamentals, XML layouts and SQLite db. [Android training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) is a great place to start. A good sample app to start with all the DB stuffs comes with the SDK installation. Path is: \samples\android-17\NotePad

Comment: Thanks Bro, but i want to clear about this type of apps can i coding & develop with only java, XML & SQ lite ??? any other more ???

Comment: Java, XML and SQ lite are the standart developing frameworks for Android apps, And also the easiest to work with in your case. You can code with C also but that makes it much more complex.

Comment: Yes. They should be enough for your app.

Comment: which format data save in sd card or dropbox in this type of app ???

Comment: Nobody is here to answer your every question. You can Google for anything you need.